# latitude / longitude formula in php solution for determining a NSWE corners from a central point

Tags: php, math, latitude-longitude, trigonometry

lat/long outward distance approx 800ft on each side from center.

**I have a central point of:**
Latitude:38.6806353
Longitude:-96.5001029

I am trying to resolve a formula with php how to get the latitude / longitude to the NWSE corners approx 800ft outward from a center point.

**So I would end up with a result similar to (but not correct):**

Central:
 
38.6806353 -96.5001029
 
N: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
 
W: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
 
S: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
 
E: 38.6806353 -96.5001029

I've been trying to reverse engineer a few Javascripts that I found, but having absolutly no luck.

Is there a php Class available that does this math or similar that would require minor revisions? I can't find one thus far...

**I found this function and I've been toying with it. I can get a nice array output like:**

```
Array ( [0] => -112.35301079549 [1] => 36.105603064867 [2] => -112.25722008867 [3] => 36.105603064867 )
```

But I can't get a N W S E coordinates set to generate? Anyone know what I am doing wrong with this? I need 4 sets of values instead of two like:

N: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
W: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
S: 38.6806353 -96.5001029
E: 38.6806353 -96.5001029

```
<?php function getBoundingBox($lon_degrees,$lat_degrees,$distance_in_miles) { 

    $radius = 3963.1; // of earth in miles

    // bearings 
    $due_north = 0;
    $due_south = 180;
    $due_east = 90;
    $due_west = 270;

    // convert latitude and longitude into radians 
    $lat_r = deg2rad($lat_degrees);
    $lon_r = deg2rad($lon_degrees);

    // find the northmost, southmost, eastmost and westmost corners $distance_in_miles away
    // original formula from
    // http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

    $northmost  = asin(sin($lat_r) * cos($distance_in_miles/$radius) + cos($lat_r) * sin ($distance_in_miles/$radius) * cos($due_north));
    $southmost  = asin(sin($lat_r) * cos($distance_in_miles/$radius) + cos($lat_r) * sin     ($distance_in_miles/$radius) * cos($due_south));

    $eastmost = $lon_r +   atan2(sin($due_east)*sin($distance_in_miles/$radius)*cos($lat_r),cos($distance_in_miles/$radius)-sin($lat_r)*sin($lat_r));
    $westmost = $lon_r + atan2(sin($due_west)*sin($distance_in_miles/$radius)*cos($lat_r),cos($distance_in_miles/$radius)-sin($lat_r)*sin($lat_r));


    $northmost = rad2deg($northmost);
    $southmost = rad2deg($southmost);
    $eastmost = rad2deg($eastmost);
    $westmost = rad2deg($westmost);

    // sort the lat and long so that we can use them for a between query        
    if ($northmost > $southmost) { 
        $lat1 = $southmost;
        $lat2 = $northmost;

    } else {
        $lat1 = $northmost;
        $lat2 = $southmost;
    }


    if ($eastmost > $westmost) { 
        $lon1 = $westmost;
        $lon2 = $eastmost;

    } else {
    $lon1 = $eastmost;
    $lon2 = $westmost;
    }

    return array($lon1,$lat1,$lon2,$lat1);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that $due_north, $due_south, etc are in degrees but you have sin($due_east) without a conversion of $due_east to radians.

For 90 deg bearing (east), θ= pi/2 (90 deg), d/R will be 800ft / 5280 ft/mi / 3959 miles (radius of earth in miles), lat1/lon1 are your center point lat/lon in radians.

```
east_lat = asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ))
east_lon = lon1 + atan2(sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1), cos(d/R)−sin(lat1)*sin(lat2))
```

Convert back to degrees then repeat for the other  3 corners.

The comment in your code references the website:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Go to the section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point**.  You can check your calculations with the calculator on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

The bounding box must satisfy some conditions you didn't mentioned. For example Google Maps uses a z curve and 21 zoom level to subdivide the map into smaller tiles. I don't know how big is a single tile in distance but I use the script from John Brafford to convert from geo coordinate to WGS84 Datum. There is also a method to return the bounding box of a tile. You can find the script here: http://bafford.com/software/aggregate-map-tools/GlobalMapTiles.php.txt.